# Moving a div by its class inside another div with an ID

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move a div with class="SomeDiv" into/inside a div with ID="ParentDiv"

If I edit the javascript to move div with ID into another div with a diff ID that works. But moving a div with Class into div with ID is not working. Am I missing something?

HTML

```
<div id="ParentDiv">
    <div id="ChildDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- move SomeDiv here -->
</div>
<div class="SomeDiv">some content</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('ParentDiv').appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gvsa/1/

Comment: Why bother including jQuery if you're not going to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jquery makes it easier, look at the updated version of your jsfiddle and you can see the item has been moved, by inspecting the dom tree

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ParentDiv").append($(".SomeDiv"));
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/fabriziopaino86/9gvsa/3/)

Answer (score 5):

`.getElementsByClassName` returns array so you need an index at the end like this:

```
document.getElementById('ParentDiv').appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv')[0]);
```

Comment: that works well in jSFiddle! Does not work at all on actual site though: http://bit.ly/13GerYd - I am trying to get the THUMBNAILS from the slider inside the ID rev_slider_1_1

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv')[0]`  instead,
`getElementsByClassName` returns a array of elements while `getElementsById` returns a single element

Answer (score 0):

Source: [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection of found elements.

If you know that your div has a unique class you can do

```
document.getElementById('ParentDiv').appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get an element of a class like that. document.getElementsByClassName returns an array. You would have to do something like...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv')[0]
```

Moreover, if you want to put all divs of that className in the div, do some iteration.

```
for (i=0;i<=document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv').length;i++) {
    document.getElementById('ParentDiv').appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('SomeDiv')[i]);
}
```